# iOS 7: Does the completion for renewCredentialsForAccount:completion: ever run with status ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed?

Tags: ios, ios7

The ACAccountStore class has a method `renewCredentialsForAccount:completion:` that will prompt the user to enter a new password for their account in the Settings app (see screenshot below). If the user hits Cancel, the completion block is called with a renewResult of ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRejected.

There are two other valid results, for which this block is (apparently?) never called: ACAccountCredentialRenewResultFailed, and ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed. In the case of ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed, the app should re-try account access, since (presumably) the user has updated their password in the Settings app.

The problem is that the completion block is never called with that status. I've seen some sample code indicating that one should subscribe to the ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification notification, and call `renewCredentialsForAccount:completion:` when that happens. This doesn't seem right either: that notification is posted if the user taps the Settings button in that prompt, so calling `renewCredentialsForAccount:completion:` at that point results in this weird interaction:

1. Call `renewCredentialsForAccount:completion:`: prompt is shown to user
2. User taps Settings button
3. Settings app is launched and notification is posted, so…
4. `renewCredentialsForAccount:completion:` is called again, and the "Enter the Twitter password" prompt is shown AGAIN but over the Settings app (which makes no sense at all)

Is there a situation under which the completion handler **is** called with a status of ACAccountCredentialRenewResultRenewed?

For my app, it will be fine if the answer is "no," but I want to make sure I'm correctly handling it if it does happen. But, since I can't cause that situation to happen, I'm unable to test any code I might put in the block for that case.

[image: Renew prompt]